# Spring Integration - Delay events by 45 minutes and then invoke a method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a requirement to delay events by 45 minutes and then invoke a method.
The events keep on coming and piling up. How to approach this using spring integration delayer or spring scheduler?

I went ahead and used JdbcMessageStore with Oracle DB. The messages are stored in INT_MESSAGE table. Somehow during retrieval we observe this error

```
            --- [             26] o.s.j.c.JdbcTemplate                     : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT MESSAGE_ID, CREATED_DATE, MESSAGE_BYTES from INT_MESSAGE where MESSAGE_ID=? and REGION=?]
 DEBUG whdq7355
            --- [             26] o.s.j.d.DataSourceUtils                  : Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
DEBUG whdq7355
            --- [             26] o.s.j.s.l.DefaultLobHandler              : Returning BLOB as bytes
DEBUG whdq7355
            --- [             26] o.s.j.d.DataSourceUtils                  : Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
DEBUG whdq7355
            --- [             26] o.s.i.c.PublishSubscribeChannel          : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00540001, headers={id=a39571b4-747b-87e7-f10f-0fa360904a15, timestamp=1566325212736}]
```

Comment: With @Scheduled(cron = "* /45 * * * ?") you should delay the event for 45 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `delayer` component in Spring Integration. It can be configured for that amount of time when you convert it into milliseconds. See Docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#delayer. Also for such a long delay you definitely need to consider to use external message store on delayer to avoid messages loss and memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can i use couchbase as the external message store. Can you please share any example or reference with delayer and message store

Comment: Examples you can see in docs I’ve mentioned. It is pretty simple: just bean reference. Only the problem that we don’t have couchbase implementation. I’m not familiar with it, but you can read about ‘MessageStore` in that doc and select whatever implementation is close to couchbase requirements, e.g. MongoDB one.

Comment: thank you, let me try to use the jdbc message store with Oracle DB. Do I need to write any special logic to handle any message loss behavior. I have few queries, sorry if I am asking irrelevant questions - how the process will know when the delay is going to expir, pick up the message from the DB and do the processing? how the process will recover itself after an abrupt shutdown?

Comment: The process stores message in the store and schedule a task to read that message from the store and emit. That's why it is called *delayer*. When your application crashes on the next start, all the stored messages are resheduled with remaining delay. I think that is clearly explained in the the docs I mentioned. If not, please, raise a GH issue and we will improve it.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I went ahead and used JdbcMessageStore with Oracle DB. The messages are stored in INT_MESSAGE table. Somwhow during retrieval error ```

Comment: And what error do you get, please? You can modify your question adding config and then the stack trace for the error you're mentioning.

Comment: Thanks Artem, I have edited the question and updated the stack trace

Comment: Yeah... for JDBC you need to be sure that your payload is a `Serializable` properly

Comment: I am passing the payload as {"name":"Test"}  - Not sure why will it fail to serialize

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198251/discussion-between-developer-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: I don't `chat` here on SO. It is very hard to follow. You need to check what your delayer really gets as an input payload. I see you send a JSON, but it doesn't mean that delayer gets exactly this text. May be it is already a `byte[]` from that JSON?..

Comment: Thanks Artem, can you please suggest what needs to be validated? Sorry for my ignorance, I am starting to use this tech stack recently

Comment: Well, `JdbcMessageStore` uses `SerializingConverter` and `WhiteListDeserializingConverter` by default with their default `DefaultSerializer` and `DefaultDeserializer` respectively. It is preforms a serialization for the whole message: `final byte[] messageBytes = this.serializer.convert(message);`. The `MessageHeaders` property ignores those keys which values are not `Serializable` during `writeObject()` phase. So, the question might be only with the `payload` or some header which is `Collection` or an array.

Comment: However it is really suspicious for me that it doesn't barf on serialization, but doesn't like deserialization... You may need to play with `SerializingConverter` and `WhiteListDeserializingConverter` against your message in isolation to figure out what might be wrong and with what.